# Datatype on output column not reflecting change to source item in SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

Take a sqlCommand in a source item:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(MKGDiagnoses.ICD9Code, 2,7) AS ICD9Code 
FROM ...
```

The column ICD9Code outputs a string with a length of 7 positions.
Now change to:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(MKGDiagnoses.ICD9Code, 2,6) AS ICD9Code 
FROM ...
```

So datatype of the column is changed to a string of **6** positions.

A change like this is never reflected in the datatype of the output columns, while the datatype of the external column did change to [DT_STR] with length 6.

[image: advanced editor]

Is this expected behaviour? Is this behaviour overwritable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expected? Sort of? I can't find an earlier answer from me on this but the basics are that the metadata gets set when the item is first created. This is an expensive operation so the designer tries to limit the number of times it must referesh the metadata and so changing the precision of a numeric or increasing/decreasing the length of a string generally isn't a "big enough" change to force a metadata refresh request.

If I changed a single column as you're demonstrating, my lazy hack would be to rename the column in my source query (and then name it back).

Original

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(MKGDiagnoses.ICD9Code, 2,7) AS ICD9Code 
FROM ...
```

Temporary

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(MKGDiagnoses.ICD9Code, 2,6) AS ICD9CodeShort 
FROM ...
```

Revert

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(MKGDiagnoses.ICD9Code, 2,6) AS ICD9Code 
FROM ...
```

If you have lots of columns to fix, I usually make the query `SELECT 1 AS foo` and then re-open the editor and use my real source query.

Comment: Isn't the change on type on the external column a result of a reevaluation of the metadata? I would expect it to change the type on the output column aswell.

Comment: yep expected, like bilinkc said, fastest thing to do rename it.